# Combine two tables and add missing values for missing ID

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following table:

```
ID | Name | Value1 | Value2  
1 | A | 1000 | 2000   
2 | A | 3000 | 4000    
1 | C | 1100 | 2200   
2 | B | 1500 | 2500
```

and I want to output the following table:

```
ID | Name | Value1 | Value2   
1 | A | 1000 | 2000   
2 | A | 3000 | 4000   
1 | C | 1100 | 2200   
2 | B | 1500 | 2500   
2 | C | 1100 | 2200   
1 | B | 1500 | 2500
```

So basically I want to replicate the missing values for each ID (ID has only two values - 1 or 2) for every Name. I can do this with a LEFT JOIN on the table itself only if I know that one ID contains all available Names. Is there a better way? I'm using SQL Server 2014.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT A1.ID, A2.NAME, ISNULL(A.Value1, A3.Value1) Value1, ISNULL(A.Value2, 
A3.Value2) Value2 FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM MyTable) A1 CROSS APPLY
(SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM MyTable) A2 OUTER APPLY
(SELECT TOP 1 Value1, Value2 FROM MyTable A3 WHERE A3.NAME = A2.NAME) A3
LEFT JOIN MyTable A ON A.ID = A1.ID AND A.NAME = A2.NAME 
ORDER BY A1.ID, A2.NAME
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks a lot.